# Do not see a label resize in tablelayoutpanel

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have a `tablelayoutpanel` and I have 5 labels on the first row (there are 4 rows). there are 5 columns and the width of the last column is the width of the scroll bar (basic scrollbar). When I put commands on the panel, the scrollbar is sometimes visible, sometimes not, and I resize my last column according to that. My problem is when I do not have the scroll bar and just after I have it: I want to resize my labels but without seeing the change happen.

I tried Suspend and Resume, but it doesn't work correctly. I tried also to set visible or not the `tablelayoutpanel` but nothing.

here the code :

```
tableLayoutPanelGroupView.ColumnStyles[5].Width = 0;
```

and after :

```
tableLayoutPanelGroupView.ColumnStyles[5].Width = SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
```

Comment: I'm sorry for my english, I'm French.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. If you have a Column which is sized as the vertical scrollbar width, when the scrollbar appears, it will overlap this column entirely. So, you won't notice any change in the size of the other columns. Just keep the column as it is. Or maybe add some more specific details to the question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't explain correctly the situation: I have a flowlayoutpanel on the tablelayoutpanel at second row (dock fill, columnspan 5, rowspan 4) and when I have the verticalScrollbar of the flowlayoutpanel, I resize the last column of the tablelayoutpanel

Comment: Make it span 4 columns instead, then. Keep the last one just as a *placeholder* for the ScrollBars.

Comment: I can't and this is not I want. My last label is resizing according to scrollbar visibility to align with components in the flowlayoutpanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution: before changing the size of my last column in the tablelayoutpanel, I set visibility of my labels to false and I reset visibility to true when I'm done.

Thanks to persons who try to help me!